# D3. Histogram Layout. How do I recalculate the histogram on the fly?

Tags: d3.js

I have a histogram created from datasource.

```
this.histogramDataSource = d3.layout.histogram()
    .value (function(d) { return d.score; })
    .bins(binThresholds)
(self.datasource);
```

That I render thusly

```
histogramRects = histogramGroup.selectAll('.svg_container rect')
    .data(histogram.histogramDataSource)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr({
        x:      function(d) { return histogram.x(d);       },
        width:  function(d) { return histogram.width(d);   },
        y:      function(d) { return histogram.y(d);       },
        height: function(d) { return histogram.height(d);  }
    })
    .attr("fill",  function(d) { return scarpa.ConnectivityScoreHistogram.fillColor(); });
```

Based on user input I want to filter the input datasource, recalculate the  histogram and re-render. I thought I could simply do something like this:

```
this.histogramDataSource(filtered_data_source);
```

But that generates errors. What have I missed here?

Comment: Looks like it should work. What error are you getting?

Comment: Lars it was my error. Confusion on the semantics of histogram layout vs. data source. Sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to keep a reference to the original histogram builder:

```
this.histogramLayout = d3.layout.histogram()
    .value (function(d) { return d.score; })
    .bins(binThresholds);

this.histogramDataSource = this.histogramLayout(self.datasource);
```

Then

```
this.histogramDataSource = this.histogramLayout(filtered_data_source);
```

However, keep in mind that this is recalculating the entire histogram from scratch so it might get a bit slow with somewhat larger data sets. If you really want interactive filtering you might want to look at Crossfilter.

Comment: Yep. It works. I got hung up on the distinction between the histogram as layout and histogram as data source when I constructed it. Cheers.